# Help! upgrade 2.x to 2.3 get error magento/framework/Setup/Declaration/Schema/Db/SchemaBuilder.php on line 152

Tags: magento2.3

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
Cache cleared successfully
File system cleanup:
/home/wwwroot/veaul/domain/veaul/web/generated/code/Composer
/home/wwwroot/veaul/domain/veaul/web/generated/code/MSP
/home/wwwroot/veaul/domain/veaul/web/generated/code/Magento
/home/wwwroot/veaul/domain/veaul/web/generated/code/Mirasvit
/home/wwwroot/veaul/domain/veaul/web/generated/code/Symfony
/home/wwwroot/veaul/domain/veaul/web/generated/code/Veaul
The directory '/home/wwwroot/veaul/domain/veaul/web/generated/metadata/' doesn't exist - skipping cleanup
Updating modules:
Schema creation/updates:
Notice: Undefined index: checkout_agreement in /home/wwwroot/veaul/domain/veaul/web/vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Declaration/Schema/Db/SchemaBuilder.php on line 152
```

Comment: can you try running `setup:di:compile` before running `setup:upgrade`

Comment: I have resloved this issue, I created a table : checkout_agenment , then fixed. but new error came out 
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`www_aaaaaa_com_dev`.`#sql-1e46_e140b0`, CONSTRAINT

Comment: creating a table will not resolve the issue.

Comment: I have tried setup:di:compile before running setup:upgrade  , but same

Comment: which custom module uses the checkout_agreement ?

Comment: can you post what's in with with your installData or InstallSchema (of that custom module)

Comment: www@iZrj9daadv01q2yawn2q4aZ:/home/wwwroot/veaul/domain/veaul/web/vendor$ find ./ -name '*.php' | xargs grep "checkout_agreement"
./magento/module-checkout-agreements/Controller/Adminhtml/Agreement/Edit.php:        $this->_coreRegistry->register('checkout_agreement', $agreementModel);
./magento/module-checkout-agreements/Model/ResourceModel/Agreement.php:        $this->_init('checkout_agreement', 'agreement_id');

Comment: ./magento/module-checkout-agreements/Model/ResourceModel/Agreement.php:            $this->getTable('checkout_agreement_store'),
./magento/module-checkout-agreements/Model/ResourceModel/Agreement.php:            $this->getConnection()->insert($this->getTable('checkout_agreement_store'), $storeArray);
./magento/module-checkout-agreements/Model/ResourceModel/Agreement.php:            ->from($this->getTable('checkout_agreement_store'), ['store_id'])

Comment: ./magento/module-checkout-agreements/Model/ResourceModel/Agreement.php:                ['cps' => $this->getTable('checkout_agreement_store')],
./magento/module-checkout-agreements/Model/ResourceModel/Agreement/Grid/Collection.php:                ['agreement_store' => 'checkout_agreement_store']
./magento/module-checkout-agreements/Model/ResourceModel/Agreement/Collection.php:            [$alias => $this->getTable('checkout_agreement_store')],

Comment: ./magento/module-checkout-agreements/Block/Adminhtml/Agreement/Edit.php:        if ($this->_coreRegistry->registry('checkout_agreement')->getId()) {
./magento/module-checkout-agreements/Block/Adminhtml/Agreement/Edit/Form.php:        $model = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('checkout_agreement');
./magento/magento2-base/dev/tests/static/testsuite/Magento/Test/Integrity/_files/dependency_test/tables_ce.php:    'checkout_agreement'                          => 'Magento\Checkout',

Comment: ./magento/magento2-base/dev/tests/static/testsuite/Magento/Test/Integrity/_files/dependency_test/tables_ce.php:    'checkout_agreement_store'                    => 'Magento\Checkout',
grep: ./magento/magento2-base/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Test/Unit/Module/Di/_files/app/code/Magento/SomeModule/etc/source/PhpExt.php: Is a directory
grep: ./oyejorge/less.php: Is a directory

Comment: www@iZrj9daadv01q2yawn2q4aZ:/home/wwwroot/veaul/domain/veaul/web/vendor$

Comment: @magefms I have posted

Comment: yeah, let me check

Comment: I've checked it already. and to be honest it's really hard to know which is causing the error according to the codes you posted

Comment: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`www_veaul_com_dev`.`#sql-1e46_e140b0`, CONSTRAINT `CAT_PRD_ENTT_DEC_ENTT_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`entity_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_product_entity` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE), query was: ALTER TABLE `catalog_product_entity_decimal` MODIFY COLUMN `entity_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0  , MODIFY COLUMN `value` decimal(12, 4)  NULL  COMMENT "Value", ADD CONSTRAINT

Comment: `CAT_PRD_ENTT_DEC_ENTT_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`entity_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_product_entity` (`entity_id`)  ON DELETE CASCADE

Comment: Are you working on a migrated db schema ? or an original one? because if that's a migrated one, you can check from your old database and look for the `checkout_agreement` table with the table that has table relation on it

Comment: from there maybe you can find the answer as to why you are getting the error

Comment: I've got the same error, but a different index --> "Notice: Undefined index: MAGcustomer_entity in /data/web/public/vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Declaration/Schema/Db/SchemaBuilder.php on line 152
"

Comment: I solved my problem: Someone did a wrong import on the database. The table `MAGcustomer_entity` wasn't supposed to be in the database.

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: magento_eav_attribute_set in /vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Declaration/Schema/Db/SchemaBuilder.php on line 152

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/156974)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/156974)